# WSo2 APM-IDP Integration Issues

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am working on securing the REST apis using Wso2 APM and IDP with postgresql as the database. Used the below link to do that
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

I was able to create the REST api, published it through Wso2 api manager , subscribed to the api and generated access token and used the api. So far it is good.

Now I go back the Application->> Production Keys to generate new access token the second time. At this point.I get the below exception with a cleanup button
"Error! You have partially created keys. Please click the Clean Up button and try again.".

Once I click on Clean Up button, I won't be able to generate the access token again. 
"role name Application/apistore_PizzaShack_PRODUCTION is already in the system.Pick up new Role".

Could you please help me out here. Why I am having issues with generating the access token the second time.

WSo2IS mastersources.xml

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

    <providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>

    <datasources>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/apimgt?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
                    <username>apiuser</username>
                    <password>apimanager</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                   <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/registry?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
                    <username>apiuser</username>
                    <password>apimanager</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2UM_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for user management</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/userstore?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;</url>
                    <username>apiuser</username>
                    <password>apimanager</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

         <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:<!-- Full path to JDBC database -->;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
         </datasource>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for message broker database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>WSO2MBStoreDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2MB_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

    </datasources>

</datasources-configuration>
```

WSo2 IS REgistry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<wso2registry>
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost">   
        <id>gov</id>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <cacheId>apiuser@jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/registry</cacheId>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>


    <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

    <dbConfig name="wso2registry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>

   <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyHandler">
 <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.registry.RegistryPolicyMediaTypeMatcher">
 <property name="mediaType">application/xacml-policy+xml</property>
       </filter>
   </handler>


    <indexingConfiguration>
        <startIndexing>false</startIndexing>
        <startingDelayInSeconds>35</startingDelayInSeconds>
        <indexingFrequencyInSeconds>5</indexingFrequencyInSeconds>
        <!--number of resources submit for given indexing thread -->
        <batchSize>40</batchSize>
        <!--number of worker threads for indexing -->
        <indexerPoolSize>40</indexerPoolSize>
        <!-- location storing the time the indexing took place-->
        <lastAccessTimeLocation>/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime</lastAccessTimeLocation>
        <!-- the indexers that implement the indexer interface for a relevant media type/(s) -->
        <indexers>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.MSExcelIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.MSPowerpointIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.MSWordIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/msword"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PDFIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/pdf"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.XMLIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/xml"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.XMLIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/(.)+\+xml"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/swagger\+json"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/(.)+\+json"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="text/(.)+"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/x-javascript"/>
        </indexers>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion pathRegEx="/_system/config/repository/dashboards/gadgets/swfobject1-5/.*[.]html"/>
            <exclusion pathRegEx="/_system/local/repository/components/org[.]wso2[.]carbon[.]registry/mount/.*"/>
        </exclusions>
    </indexingConfiguration>


    <versionResourcesOnChange>false</versionResourcesOnChange>

    <!-- NOTE: You can edit the options under "StaticConfiguration" only before the
     startup. -->
    <staticConfiguration>
        <versioningProperties>true</versioningProperties>
        <versioningComments>true</versioningComments>
        <versioningTags>true</versioningTags>
        <versioningRatings>true</versioningRatings>
    </staticConfiguration>
</wso2registry>
```

My apologies I pasted the wrong registry.xml. I pasted the correct one now. Could you please help me find the issue - why I am getting the exception the second time I try to generate the access token.

Comment: My apologies I pasted the wrong registry.xml before. I pasted the correct one now. Could you please help me find the issue - why I am getting the exception the second time I try to generate the access token.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you haven't shared Registry/UM databases properly among IS (KM) and APIM nodes. Please double check your `master-datasources.xml` and `registry.xml` files. If you need any help with configuring them properly, please update your question with your configurations.

Update: The problem is with `registry.xml` configurations, as I suspected. You need to mount registry (share registry database) among 2 servers. How it's done is explained in step 9 of the same document you're referring.

Comment: Added the xmls for WSo2 IS configuration.

Comment: Bhatiya, Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Bhatiya...I m still not able to understand the issue here . As per step Step 9) Make the following change to the  <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml file. Create the registry mounts by inserting the following sections into the registry.xml file. However I did the same changes . I have added the dbconfig to "govregistry" without making any change the dbconfig associated with "wso2registry". Could you please be more specific on what changes I have to make.

Comment: Bhatiya..I copied the wrong registry.xml in the question before...actually I have added  the dbconfig to "govregistry" without making any change the dbconfig associated with "wso2registry". Could you please check the xml now

Comment: Your config looks correct. Maybe there are some data inconsistancy in databases. Can you clean all postgresql databases and h2 databases and restart servers with `-Dsetup` option? (To remove H2 databases, delete all files inside `repository/database/`)

Comment: 1) I dropped all the database recreated it in postgresql

Comment: 1) I dropped all the databases and recreated it in postgresql 2) Removed the h2 files from repository/databases from both API and IS directories 3) restarted the server  with -Dsetup option. This didn't fix my issue. I am able to generate the production keys for the first time. In the second time, when I click on the production keys tab, I get an exception " "Error! You have partially created keys. Please click the Clean Up button and try again".

Comment: q1) Do you have 'jdbc/WSO2AM_DB' for datasource in identity.xml as well? That's the default actually. Did you change it by any chance?
q2) Are you sure both `master-datasources.xml` and `registry.xml` files in both APIM and IS servers are identical?

Comment: Bhathiya...I created a new instance of WSo2 API and Ws02 IDM and started everything from scratch. It's almost the same configuration that I used before. However everything works now. I really don't know what went wrong before.But thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad to hear that.